# Android Change ImageButton image

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I write an travel APP.There are 20 QR Code in every spot.

When tourist use QR Code scanner scan the QR Code,the ImageButton's image have to change into another image.

The problem on this line ： spot1.setImageResource(R.drawable.hotspot1);

If I delete this line, there is no problem.

I don't know how to fix it.

```
     @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if (0 == requestCode && null != data && data.getExtras() != null) {
     String result = data.getExtras().getString("la.droid.qr.result");
     int spotnum=Integer.valueOf(result);
     switch(spotnum){
        case 1:
            ImageButton spot1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
            spot1.setImageResource(R.drawable.hotspot1);
            setContentView(R.layout.hotspot1);
            break;
        case 2:
            setContentView(R.layout.hotspot2);
            break;
   }
  }
 }
```

Here is my Logcat：https://i.stack.imgur.com/6y2UQ.png

Comment: Are you asking a question?  It looks like you have some code, but what is the problem?

Comment: what is there in main Activity line number 133?

Comment: try to call  setContentView(R.layout.hotspot1); berfore spot1 initialization.

Comment: @DroidMind      public void info(View view){ 
     setContentView(R.layout.spotlist);
    }

Comment: It seems to be a nullpointer, and it may be because "spot1==null". Try: 1-setting your content view before this call, 2-checking if you have initialized your variable, 3- checking if the id for your "findViewById" is the correct one.

Comment: the smae.@HareshChhelana

Answer (score 1):

You can not initialize any Views from xml before calling setContentView :

```
setContentView(R.layout.hotspot1);
ImageButton spot1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
spot1.setImageResource(R.drawable.hotspot1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not suppose to call `setContentView` after setting view resource. call set contentView once in `onCreate` without setting any view from xml.

You can then change the layout contents, but do not call `setContentView` again.

You are using a `image view`, but not calling `setContentView` before it. This makes the `ImageView` as null, hence the error.

Try following above suggestions,and it will go. Happy Coding.